# Adding hash for google analytics 4 with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hash, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Does anyone encountered issue with adding hashed value?
Didn't found inside [react-ga4 docs](https://github.com/codler/react-ga4) how to implement it using `ReactGA.initialize()`.

So far did it with JS by finding script in html head and adding additional tags `crossorigin` and `integrity`  with hash, but then get :

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={MY_MEASSUREMENT)_ID}' with computed SHA-256 integrity {SHA256_CODE}. The resource has been blocked
```

Read a bit [google docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/csp), but nothing particular with hashes. Maybe someone knows solution?